# How can I change tags on a Steam Workshop item?

Tags: modding, marketing, steam, steamworks

A few years ago, I posted a [L4D2 modification](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=248697266) to the game Workshop on Steam.

I'd like to be able to change the tags associated with the mod (currently, 'Weapons, UI') but it's not obvious to me how I should edit the mod profile to make this change.

If anybody can tell me how to do this, I'd appreciate it!